# FileNotFoundException when try to play video in VideoView Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have xyz.mp4 file in "/videos" folder and i want to play it in VideoView, but i get error:

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open /data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/files/videos/xyz.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/files/videos/xyz.mp4
```

My code:

```
var videoUri: Uri = Uri.parse(applicationContext.filesDir.path.toString() + "/videos/xyz.mp4")

videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri)
videoView.requestFocus()
videoView.start()
```

When I want to play this video from folder raw:

```
val videoUri: Uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.xyz)
```

all works fine. How to solve this?

Comment: That folder is private to your app. Better use getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: Use `Uri.fromFile()`, not `Uri.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the video in the 'raw' folder and by that I mean
There should be only that 'xyz.mp4' video inside your 'raw' folder
(Example: raw/xyz.mp4 ✔
Not raw/data/user)
Try this thing first and if that doesn't work I'll tell you other one